# Using induction show the following

Tags: discrete-mathematics

using induction, I am supposed to show that 3n < n! whenever is an integer with n > 7. So here is what I did:

Base case:

P(n) (let n = 7) therefore:

P(7) = 3(7) < 7! (does that mean that 21 is not less than 7?) I'm a bit confused by this question. If that is the case, we know by Induction that P(n) -> P(n + 1) so therefore P(8) = 3

Comment: I guess my question is what does ! mean?

Comment: 7!  (7 factorial) is $1*2*3*4*5*6*7=5040.  n!=1*2*3.....*n.

Comment: I'm wondering if you wrote the question correctly.  If $n > 3$ the proposition is true.   It would a good illustration (albeit obvious) of induction as n! = n (n-1)! And (n-1)! > 3.

Comment: Thanks, after some digging I found out it meant factorial I'm sorry I didn't respond until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$`!\'$ here refers to the factorial function on natural numbers. For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n!$ is defined as $n!=n(n-1)(n-2)...(2)(1)$ or it can be recursively defined as $n!=n(n-1)!$ where $0!=1.$

So in your question, $7!=7*6*5*4*3*2*1=5040$ which is clearly much larger than $21.$

Comment: Thanks, after some digging online, I found out what it meant. Many thinks Maryam.